# merge object in php

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter

i have below json data

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "minggu a": "2",
            "total a": "377033"
        },
        {
            "minggu b": "1",
            "total b": "136615"
        }
    ]
```

and this is the code i made in controller

```
$satu= $this->model->db_week_resTender();
     $arr = [];
     foreach($satu as $val){
        $arr['data'][] = array(
            'minggu' => $val['minggu'],
            'total'  => $val['total']
        );
     }
     $response =  $this->set_response($arr,200);
}
```

how to concatenate below json data
here I issue data with a limit of 2.

```
  {
        "data": [
            {
                "minggu a": "2",
                "total a": "377033"
                "minggu b": "1",
                "total b": "136615"
            },
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = '{
       "data": [
                {
                  "minggu a": "2",
                  "total a": "377033"
                },{
                  "minggu b": "1",
                  "total b": "136615"
                  }
                ]
          }';

$decoded_satu=json_decode($data,true);
$arr = [];
foreach($decoded_satu['data'] as $key=> $val){
        foreach ($val as $subkey => $subvalue) {
                $arr['data'][$subkey] = $subvalue;
        }
}

$finalArray = json_encode($arr);
echo "<pre>";print_r($finalArray) ;die;
```

Comment: for a better answer you need to add a description of the answer you provided.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($statu as $index => $val){
    $arr['data'][$index] = $val;
}
```

This should give the result you have posted at the end.

Comment: It shouldn't. `$satu` (not `$statu`) contains `data`, which would be duplicated

Comment: doesn't work, the result is the same as above